# Getting the property key from within a property's value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given the following javascript object:

```
var commands = {
    back:{
        command: "b",
        aliases: ["back","go back","backwards"],
        action: function(){
            return this.key; //I want this to return "back" (the prop name)
        },
        desc: "goes back"
    }
}
```

How can i access the Property Name which is "back" from within the `action()`?

I think it should be pretty simple, but if it isn't something simple than I'll add more details.

- NOTE: `aliases[0]` is holding the name by chance, and it is not promised to hold it in the future or in other commands.

EDIT:
Sometimes we get to complicated while we can solve the problem pretty fast.
In this case i can just go ahead and return the string "back"

I'll leave the question and accept the answer that solves my question if there is such a solution.

Comment: Would adding a redundant `name: "back"` property to the object be suitable for you? Or maybe just using `this.aliases[0]` if it's always the name?

Comment: The only way would be to iterate `commands`'s properties and check for value equality with `this`. But this really depends on whether `commands` is always available inside the closure.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi aliases[0] is not promised to hold the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the string as you mentioned is definitely the easiest way. But I could see cases where someone might want to be able to get similar functionality with a dynamically created object in which the keys are not known until run-time.

A solution that would work in that case is exposing the `commands` object to the sub objects, so they can look themselves up:

```
var commands = {
    back:{
        command: "b",
        aliases: ["back","go back","backwards"],
        action: function(){
            var commandKeys = Object.keys(commands);
            for(var i=0; i < commandKeys.length; i++){
                if(commands[commandKeys[i]] === this){
                    return commandKeys[i];
                }
            }
        },
        desc: "goes back"
    }
};
```

In this case it may also make more sense to share the function across all those action objects:

```
var commands = {
    back:{
        command: "b",
        aliases: ["back","go back","backwards"],
        action: getAction,
        desc: "goes back"
    },
    forward: {
        //...
        action: getAction,
        //...
    }
};

function getAction() {
    var commandKeys = Object.keys(commands);
    for(var i=0; i < commandKeys.length; i++){
        if(commands[commandKeys[i]] === this){
            return commandKeys[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you need to perform some specific logic for each sub object.

---

**EDIT:** To improve efficiency, we can make it where the `getAction` function is not executed every call and add a property that will store the name. That way the lookup only occurs the first time.

```
var commands = {
    back:{
        command: "b",
        aliases: ["back","go back","backwards"],
        action: getAction,
        desc: "goes back"
    },
    forward: {
        //...
        action: getAction,
        //...
    }
};
// Only needs to getKey the first time called.
function getAction() {
    if(!this.key) this.key = getKey(this);
    return this.key;
}
function getKey(obj) {
    var commandKeys = Object.keys(commands);
    for(var i=0; i < commandKeys.length; i++){
        if(commands[commandKeys[i]] === obj){
            return commandKeys[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not the most efficient answer but definitely the only one that answers my question :)

Comment: @TBE, I just added an edit that hopefully NanoWizard will approve that should increase the efficiency of the code in this very nice solution:)

Comment: @tkellehe I didn't reject it... Maybe it timed out? I just now got back online and I don't see your edits. I assume it was caching/sorting of the `commandKeys`?

Comment: It did not show on my phone why it was rejected just that it was. I see now as to why. Instead of commenting I will just resubmit the edit so you can see it then you can reject it and choose whether or not to update the answer:)

Comment: I changed it a little for clarity, but it's a good efficiency improvement. Thanks :)

Comment: @NanoWizard. Thank you:) Yeah, I like your wording better haha.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `action` as the following:

```
commands.back.action();
```

the scope of `action` is `back`. Sadly, the creation of the object that gets assigned to `commands.back` does not know that `this` inside of `action` is called `"back"`. From my understanding, this is done because we could assign the object assigned to `commands.back` to another object with another name. As in:

```
var foo = { f: function(){console.log(this) } };
var bar = foo;
bar.f();
```

Or closer to what you have...

```
var foo = {
    bar: {
        f:function(){console.log(this)}
    }
};
var other = { another: (foo.bar) };
```

---

The only way I know of where the object knows the name of what it was created within are functions. So, we can create a temp function that has the name `back` that will create an object as desired.

```
var commands = {
    back:(new function back(){
        // I prefer to assign to a variable to assist with the readability as to what "this" is:)
        var self     = this;
        self.command = "b";
        self.aliases = ["back","go back","backwards"];
        self.action  = function(){
            // Can leave as "this" or change to "self".
            return this.key;
        };
        self.desc = "goes back";
        self.key  = self.prototype.constructor.name;
    })
}
```

---

**Simplest Solution**

But at that point might as well just add a property that already has the name. I would recommend doing a property called `key` or `name` rather than placing the name directly into the `action` function to make it easier to have multiple places where the name is used. Also, allows there to be a single place to change the name within the object if need be.

```
var commands = {
    back:{
        command: "b",
        aliases: ["back","go back","backwards"],
        action: function(){
            return this.key;
        },
        desc: "goes back",
        key: "back"
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Added this edit as another way to do this, but I would still do the previous way. We can utilize `Object.keys` to get the name of the property since `back` is being added as an enumerable property of `commands`.

```
var i        = 0,
    commands = { back: {
        key: (function(id){return function(){return Object.keys(commands)[id]}})(i++)
    }}
```

Then can get the `key` by the following:

```
commands.back.key();
```

Or within the `action` function as:

```
this.key();
```

Can add `key` to `back` as a `get` which would look like:

```
var i        = 0,
    commands = { back: { 
        id: (i++),
        get key() {return Object.keys(commands)[this.id]}
    }}
```

This will allow you to access the property as `commands.back.key` and within the `action` function as `this.key`.

Can also pre-define everything then can do the following:

```
var i = 0, commands = { back: undefined };
commands.back = { key: Object.keys(commands)[i++] };
```

Comment: upVoted, just adding a property with name or just return the name as a string is probably the simplest and easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can add and also advisable to add a `toString` method for your every object like this.

```
var commands = {
back:{
    command: "b",
    name : "back",
    aliases: ["back","go back","backwards"],
    action: function(){
        return this.toString(); 
    },
    desc: "goes back",
    toString : function(){
      return this.name;
    }
 }
}
console.log(commands.back.action()); // back
console.log(commands.back.toString()); // back
```

Comment: upVoted, just adding a property with name or just return the name as a string is probably the simplest and easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

What you are having here, is a nested object, held on the property of an object.

You can not get that property by hand - unless you are doing some strange metaprogramming stuff, such as getting the AST parent node and trying to determine the property the object is held etc. The easiest way, is to hold the property name using a string i.e.: "back".

In simple terms, it is like holding the object to a var

```
var obj = {/*....*/};
```

And you are trying to get the var name from within the object.

Remember though that in JavaScript, you can access an object property, using both string and index notation, so `commands.back` can also be called using `commands['back']`. If I am guessing right, you are trying to make a sort of dispatching, so this notation can be useful for you.

Comment: There are no constructors here, and the only function the OP has used doesn't have a name.

Comment: @NickL. My need was to use that name to get a constant string from a properties file, but as u mentioned and as i wrote in my first EDIT, the simplest thing here is to just return the string "back"

Answer (score 0):

If you've got that object (literal object) you can't use `this` keyword. You have two solutions:

```
   return commands.back.aliases[0]
```

Or otherwise,you can construct the object as a prototype object and not literal object:

```
var commands = function() {

  this.back = function() {
    this.command = "b";
    this.aliases = ["back","go back","backwards"];
    this.action = function() {
      return this.aliases[0];
    };
    this.desc = "goes back";
  };
};
```

And initialize like this

```
var instance = new commands();
instance.action(); // it returns "back" string
```

Comment: aliases[0] is not promised to hold the name of the property.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstanding the question. I will remove the answer